# For which $n$ the matrix multiplication in $M_n(F)$ is commutative ?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

So for $n=0$ and $n=1$, I know matrix multiplication is commutative, but I'm confused as to how to prove that matrix multiplication is not commutative in general for $n\geq 2$. Should I use induction on $n$ or proof by contradiction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can find a pair of matrices that don't commute for $N$, then for all $n \geq N$ you can take those  two matrices as upper left blocks in a matrix where the rest of the columns are fixed ( geometrically, if you've found two linear transformations for dimension $N$, then for any $n > N$, perform those linear transformations on a subspace of dimension $N$ and fix the rest of the space ).

Now just find two matrices of dimension $2$ that don't commute.  May I suggest a rotation and a reflection?  Is $F$ a general field?

Comment: Yes F is a general field. Thank you for your help! I think I get the idea now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B_1,\ldots,B_m$ be $n \times n$ matrices with coefficients in a field $F$.  If $A$ commutes with each of $B_1,\ldots,B_m$, then also $A$ commutes with $\alpha_1 B_1 + \ldots + \alpha_m B_m$ for all $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m \in F$.

This suggests that you should look for a nice, simple basis $\{E_1,\ldots,E_{n^2}\}$ of $M_n(F)$ as an $F$-vector space.  Then $M_n(F)$ is commutative iff for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n^2$, $E_i$ and $E_j$ commute.

If you choose the most obvious basis then $E_i E_j - E_j E_i$ is easy to compute once and for all, and you are led to the standard commutation relations for [matrix units](http://planetmath.org/matrixunit), which shows that $M_n(F)$ is not commutative for all $n \geq 2$ and can be useful for other things besides.